# Can I use macros while defining postfix template?

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I assume it's possible, cause there is `'foo'.var` and it expands to `$foo = 'var';`, so there has to be some way.

What i'm trying to do is to create a template that does the following:
`FooBar.new -> $fooBar = new FooBar();`.

The best what I had by far is:
`$$$EXPR$ = new $EXPR$();`, which behaves like this:
`FooBar.new -> $FooBar = new FooBar();`.

It's almost what I want, but the variable name is capitalized. I've tried with `suggestVariableName` taken from [Template Macros](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Template_Macros.html), but I guess it only works inside live templates or I don't know how to use it for postfix completion.

**UPDATE**
I've found a really cool [plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9862-custom-postfix-templates), which does what I need. Kudos to the author!

Comment: I would suggest submitting this at JetBrains issue tracker at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue for developers to look into & advise. I'm also unable to find any relevant references with examples or applicable templates